# Using SetFields with MongoDB C# driver 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, filtering, mongodb-.net-driver

With the old driver I could specify the fields I wanted to return from a query as follows:

```
var cursor = Collection.Find(query).
  SetFields(Fields<MealPlan>.Exclude (plan => plan.Meals));
```

How do I accomplish this with the 2.0 driver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `Projection` method on `IFindFluent` (which is what `Find` and `Projection` return):

```
var findFluent = Collection.Find(query).Projection(Fields<MealPlan>.Exclude (plan => plan.Meals))
```

Now, this would eventually generate a cursor of `BsonDocument`s since it doesn't know how the projection looks. You can call the generic `Projection` instead to add that type:

```
var findFluent = Collection.Find(query).Projection<MealPlan>(Fields<MealPlan>.Exclude (plan => plan.Meals))
```

---

In a more general sense (which is less relevant when using `Exclude`), you could also specify fields using a lambda expression:

```
var findFluent = Collection.Find(query).Projection(plan => plan.Meals)
```

Comment: Thanks. I know the driver is in beta, but will the generic projection support abstract classes? I'm assuming the serializer has access to the discriminator to determine the concrete type.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Graeme Do you mean something like `Collection.Find(query).Projection<AbstractPlan>(Fields.Include("_id"))`? No, it won't work as it tries to create an instance out of `AbstractPlan`. It can work if the base class isn't abstract but the instance would be of the base class and not the concrete type.

Comment: Actually, I think that as long as the discriminator was there (in the projection), it should work. It would certainly come back typed as the base class and require a downcast, but underneath, in this case, we are just using the AbstractPlan serializer and it knows how to deal with discriminators. I haven't tried this though, so...

Comment: @CraigWilson just did. It does work when the discriminator is added (which unlike `_id` isn't returned by default from mongo)

Comment: @i3arnon How would you go about including the discriminator in a Fields<TDocument> object? Or would I have to use the non-generic version?

Comment: @Graeme AFAIK you would have to use the non-generic version as the discriminator doesn't appear on your class (by default)

Comment: how to project array string? is there any good tutorial for 2.0 driver?

Answer (score 0):

If you want SetFields back you can write your own extension method:

```
 public static class MongoExtensions
{
    public static IFindFluent<T, T> SetFields<T>(this IFindFluent<T, T> query, params string[] fields)
    {
        if ( fields == null || fields.Length == 0 )
        {
            return query;
        }

        var project = Builders<T>.Projection.IncludeAll<T>(fields);

        return query.Project<T>(project);
    }


    public static ProjectionDefinition<T> IncludeAll<T>(this ProjectionDefinitionBuilder<T> projection,
        params string[] fields)
    {
        ProjectionDefinition<T> project = null;

        foreach (string columnName in fields)
        {
            if (project == null)
            {
                project = Builders<T>.Projection.Include(columnName);
            }
            else
            {
                project = project.Include(columnName);
            }
        }
        return project;

    }
}
```