# Getting a error while including particular field to get data from MongoDB using C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I am trying to set the particular field using Collecion.SetFields method to get specific data from  MongoDB using c#. But it's showing me error:

'IFindFluent<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>' does not contain a definition for 'SetFields' and no accessible extension method 'SetFields' accepting a first argument of type.

This is the code which i am using:

```
public MongoCursor<BsonDocument> GetRecordsAsynchronously(string runnumber, string fileType)
{
    var collection = Database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(_collectionName);
    var bsonQueryDocument = new QueryDocument(new BsonDocument() { { "RunNumber", runnumber }, { "FileType", fileType } });
    var record = collection.Find(bsonQueryDocument);            
    record.SetFields(Fields.Include("ProcessedData", "Status", "Filename"));
    return record;
}
```

I have already tried code like below and some other also :

```
var cursor = collection.Find<BsonDocument>(Query.EQ("RunNumber", runnumber));
cursor.SetFields(Fields.Include("ProcesrecordsedData", "Status", "Filename"));
return cursor;
```

Thanks for the Suggestions and help in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm used to interfacing with mongo through js rather than c# but it looks like the problem is that record is a cursor rather than a document. try chaining `FirstOrDefault()` onto your `Find`, or if you're expecting a bunch of documents you can do `ToList()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I have tried this and i am getting the same error.It is not working for me

Comment: Ah apologies, maybe also try Projection() as suggested in this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541082/using-setfields-with-mongodb-c-sharp-driver-2-0